# In Unity, why does my Hose particle system only show up in the scene preview?

Tags: unity, particles

I added particle system package from assets, selected hose particle system and put it in the scene. When I select 'Water Shower', it works in the scene preview, but on play, it just appears and vanishes in a fraction of a second. I set Looping, Play on awake enabled already, no result.

I also get the same result in a separate otherwise empty project.

[image]

Is this the problem with the prefab or there is something else I need to set to make it work properly?

I am trying to use hose particle system to create fountain like effect. I have used Steam particle system from same package, and it renders in play mode fine.

I know this is similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754148/unity-particle-system-cannot-appear-in-game-scene).  I have already tried the solutions provided there, and the asker also has not yet marked answer as a solution.

I've also made a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuj2ib4ozbw23wf/ParticleSystemBug.3gp?dl=0) of what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that issue by disabling the scripts on the parent object of hose, Happy Game Development.

**As directed below in picture, disable both red circled scripts.**

[image]

*If still problem persist you can ask in detail.*